# asp.net URL like www.example.com/(S(tx5h2k3fhz3uicis3vbrga55))/mypage.aspx

Tags: asp.net

I want to create asp.net dynamic url webpage lik

asp.net URL like `www.example.com/(S(tx5h2k3fhz3uicis3vbrga55))/mypage.aspx`

How can I create it ?

Comment: I don't think you can have parentheses in URLs.

Answer (score 1):

URL will be displayed when you set `cookielesssession` to "true". Open the web.config file and insert `<sessionState cookieless="true" />`.

```
<system.web>
    .....
    <sessionState cookieless="true" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to achieve it - basically, you have to generate tokens that need to be used in url (for random tokens, you may use GUIDs), you need to write Http Module that will intercept the url, extract the token from it and pass the control to actual http handler (page) along with the token.

Fortunately, this has already been built into ASP.NET 4 - take a look at [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).